# drupal 7 customize row style with module views

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7, view, customization

I have created a view with the module views. I would like to customize the rendering of the single row but can't find which template I have to create.
In the "Page: Theming information" section of the edit of my view, I can see these suggestions:

Display output: views-view.tpl.php (File not found, in folder ./), views-view--rank.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--page.tpl.php, views-view--rank--page.tpl.php

Style output: views-view-unformatted.tpl.php (File not found, in folder ./), views-view-unformatted--rank.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--page.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--rank--page.tpl.php

Row style output: .tpl.php, --rank.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --page.tpl.php, --rank--page.tpl.php

Why the prefix for the Row style output suggestions are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Check this path please sites/all/modules/views/theme/ , if you don't have any templates there then reinstall views